# Rails user defined views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create user defined views in Rails.

I have a `uview` record for each view.  It contains an hstore field called `ufields`.  In `ufields` I'm storing the names of the columns to be used in the table view.

I can create the table's `thead` like this:

```
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <% uview.ufields.each do |key, val| %>
        <th><%= key %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  </thead>
```

But, how can I define the fields for the `tbody`.

This doesn't work:

```
  <tr>
    <% uview.ufields.each do |key, val| %>
        <% ufield = "vehicle." + key %>
        <td><%= ufield %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
```

That just puts out rows like this `vehicle.name`.

Is there a way to have this happen? `<td><%= vehicle.name %>`

This doesn't work, but might give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
             <td><%= <%= ufield %> %></td>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you want to turn into the table view? That would help understand how data is stored (i.e. JSON?) and how we can manipulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<% uview.ufields.each do |key, val| %>
    <td><%= vehicle[key] %></td>
<% end %>
```

Actually you could be tempted to do:

```
vehicle.send key
vehicle.public_send key
```

But you'd expose to serious flaws since you trust user's inputs

---

An alternative would be to have in vehicle class:

```
WHITELISTED_USER_ATTRS = %w(name id) #add what you need but not stuff like destroy etc...

def user_input(key)
  if WHITELISTED_USER_ATTRS.include?(key.to_s)
    vehicle.send key
  else
    ""
  end
end
```

Then in the view:

```
<% uview.ufields.each do |key, val| %>
    <td><%= vehicle.user_input(key) %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: apneadiving - `<td><%= vehicle[key] %>` works great!  Is there a way to handle lookup tables?  If key = 'site' and val = 'name', I want the `<td>` to be vehicle.site.name - I tried `vehicle[key][val]`

Comment: you should really abstract it to a method